# Why can't I use data-* as a directive's attribute name in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

On the t[his plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l3KoY3?p=preview) you can notice a strange behavior with the attribute name's pattern `data-*` in a directive.

The call :

```
<body ng-app="apptest" ng-controller="Controller">
  Test of data named attribute :
  <br/>
  <directivetest data-test="vartest" test="vartest" another-test="vartest"></directivetest>
</body>
```

of the directive :

```
angular.module('apptest', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.vartest = "This is a test";
    }
  ])
  .directive('directivetest', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        dataTest: '=',
        test: '=',
        anotherTest: '='
      },
      templateUrl: "directive.html"
    }
  });
```

will take all the attributes of `directivetest` into account but `data-test` and therefore display :

> ```
> Test of data named attribute :
> Attribute with data-* name :
> Attribute with regular name : This is a test
> Attribute with an other regular name : This is a test
> ```

I am wondering why this happens (I wasted 4 hours before I figured out that it was the issue).

It seems to be impossible to name a directive `data-*`, why is that?

I read something about it here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp, is it why my attribute is undefined? It is simply not read by the browser?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `data-` prefixed forms of directive names allow HTML validators to work because [**custom data attributes**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#custom-data-attribute) in HTML5 follow that form.  AngularJS directive names are [**normalized**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives) as follows to support custom data attributes:

> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> - Strip `x-` and `data-` from the front of the element/attributes.
> - Convert the `:`, `-`, or `_`-delimited name to camelCase.

Comment: Thank you from the future. Spent half a day trying to figure out why my perfectly benign-looking directive was not loading before figuring out that the name itself was the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Angular automatically normalizes the attributes.  Things like `data-test="..."`, `x-test="..."`, and `test="..."` are considered to be the same.  You should choose one way of writing your custom attributes and stick with it; not mixing and matching.

Answer (score -1):

This is because Angular strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes. Thus in your case you have two attributes named test and one overwrites the other. I've forked your plunker as an example: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DXtIcUDmW0MBLze8Cdi3?p=preview)

```
<directivetest data-foo="vartest" test="vartest" another-test="vartest"></directivetest>

scope: {
    foo: '=',
    test: '=',
    anotherTest: '='
}
```