# Angular directive isn't compiled at ES6

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I try to build a directive with ES6 class and get it compiled, but fail. Here is the definition and how the directive is added into the app.

dataDiagram.js

```
export default class dataDiagram {
  constructor() {
    this.restrict = 'E';
    this.template = '<div>This is my directive.</div>';
    this.scope = false;
  }
}
```

app.js

```
import dataDiagram from 'dataDiagram';

angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('dataDiagram', () => new dataDiagram());
```

Then I add the `<data-diagram></data-diagram>` into my `index.html`, and expect it will become `<data-diagram><div>This is my directive.</div></data-diagram>`. However, the DOM remain to be `<data-diagram></data-diagram>` after I reload the app, and the directive isn't compiled. No error is thrown during the process.

I would like to know if I miss something when I write the code. Thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you chose unfortunate name for your directive. Angular stips `data-` prefixes when it parses template, which means that `<data-diagram></data-diagram>` (essentially is the same as `<diagram></diagram>`) corresponds to `diagram` directive, not `dataDiargam`.

Just change the name of the directive (e.g. `.directive('someDataDiagram', () => new dataDiagram());`).

Comment: Thanks, @dfsq. This saves me several hours :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [ng-annotations](https://github.com/PillowPillow/ng-annotations), it makes simple to read all the classes that you use in angular. Try changing the name of your directive by testDirective, otherwise you will have this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942069/why-cant-i-use-data-as-a-directives-attribute-name-in-angular-js)